# ruby syntax code involving hashes

Tags: ruby, arrays, syntax, hash

I was looking at code regarding how to return a mode from an array and I ran into this code:

```
def mode(array)

    answer = array.inject ({}) { |k, v| k[v]=array.count(v);k}

    answer.select { |k,v| v == answer.values.max}.keys


end
```

I'm trying to conceptualize what the syntax means behind it as I am fairly new to Ruby and don't exactly understand how hashes are being used here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line by line:

```
answer = array.inject ({}) { |k, v| k[v]=array.count(v);k}
```

This assembles a hash of counts. I would not have called the variable `answer` because it is not the answer, it is an intermediary step. The `inject()` method (also known as `reduce()`) allows you to iterate over a collection, keeping an accumulator (e.g. a running total or in this case a hash collecting counts). It needs a starting value of `{}` so that the hash exists when attempting to store a value. Given the array `[1,2,2,2,3,4,5,6,6]` the counts would look like this: `{1=>1, 2=>3, 3=>1, 4=>1, 5=>1, 6=>2}`.

```
answer.select { |k,v| v == answer.values.max}.keys
```

This selects all elements in the above hash whose value is equal to the maximum value, in other words the highest. Then it identifies the `keys` associated with the maximum values. Note that it will list multiple values if they share the maximum value.

An alternative:

If you didn't care about returning multiple, you could use group_by as follows:

```
array.group_by{|x|x}.values.max_by(&:size).first
```

or, in Ruby 2.2+:

```
array.group_by{&:itself}.values.max_by(&:size).first
```

Answer (score 0):

The `inject` method acts like an accumulator. Here is a simpler example:

```
sum = [1,2,3].inject(0) { |current_tally, new_value| current_tally + new_value }
```

The 0 is the starting point.

So after the first line, we have a hash that maps each number to the number of times it appears.

The mode calls for the most frequent element, and that is what the next line does: selects only those who are equal to the maximum.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your question has been answered, and @Mark mentioned different ways to do the calculations. I would like to just focus on other ways to improve the first line of code:

```
answer = array.inject ({}) { |k, v| k[v] = array.count(v); k }
```

First, let's create some data:

```
array = [1,2,1,4,3,2,1]
```

**Use `each_with_object` instead of `inject`**

My suspicion is that the code might be fairly old, as [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object), which was introduced in v. 1.9, is arguably a better choice here than [Enumerable#inject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) (aka `reduce`). If we were to use `each_with_object`, the first line would be:

```
answer = array.each_with_object ({}) { |v,k| k[v] = array.count(v) }
  #=> {1=>3, 2=>2, 4=>1, 3=>1}
```

`each_with_object` returns the object, a hash held by the block variable `v`.

As you see, `each_with_object` is very similar to `inject`, the only differences being:

- it is not necessary to return `v` from the block to `each_with_object`, as it is with `inject` (the reason for that annoying `; v` at the end of `inject`'s block);
- the block variable for the object (`k`) follows `v` with `each_with_object`, whereas it proceeds `v` with `inject`; and
- when not given a block, `each_with_object` returns an enumerator, meaning it can be chained to other other methods (e.g., `arr.each_with_object.with_index ...`.

Don't get me wrong, `inject` remains an extremely powerful method, and in many situations it has no peer.

**Two more improvements**

In addition to replacing `inject` with `each_with_object`, let me make two other changes:

```
answer = array.uniq.each_with_object ({}) { |k,h| h[k] = array.count(k) }
  #=> {1=>3, 2=>2, 4=>1, 3=>1}
```

In the original expression, the object returned by `inject` (sometimes called the "memo") was represented by the block variable `k`, which I am using to represent a hash key ("k" for "key"). Simlarly, as the object is a hash, I chose to use `h` for its block variable. Like many others, I prefer to keep the block variables short and use names that indicate object type (e.g., `a` for array, `h` for hash, `s` for string, `sym` for symbol, and so on).

Now suppose:

```
array = [1,1]
```

then `inject` would pass the first `1` into the block and then compute `k[1] = array.count(1) #=> 2`, so the hash `k` returned to `inject` would be `{1=>2}`. It would then pass the second `1` into the block, again compute `k[1] = array.count(1) #=> 2`, overwriting `1=>1` in `k` with `1=>1`; that is, not changing it at all. Doesn't it make more sense to just do this for the unique values of `array`? That's why I have: `array.uniq...`.

**Even better: use a counting hash**

This is still quite inefficient--all those `counts`. Here's a way that reads better and is probably more efficient:

```
array.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |k,h| h[k] += 1 }
  #=> {1=>3, 2=>2, 4=>1, 3=>1}
```

Let's have a look at this in gory detail. Firstly, the docs for [Hash#new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) read, "If `obj` is specified [i.e., `Hash.new(obj)`], this single object will be used for all default values." This means that if:

```
h = Hash.new('cat')
```

and `h` does not have a key `dog`, then:

```
h['dog'] #=> 'cat'
```

Important: The last expression is often misunderstood. It merely returns the default value. `str = "It does *not* add the key-value pair 'dog'=>'cat' to the hash."` Let me repeat that: `puts str`.

Now let's see what's happening here:

```
enum = array.each_with_object(Hash.new(0))
  #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1]:each_with_object({})>
```

We can see the contents of the enumerator by converting it to an array:

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [[1, {}], [2, {}], [1, {}], [4, {}], [3, {}], [2, {}], [1, {}]]
```

These seven elements are passed into the block by the method `each`:

```
enum.each { |k,h| h[k] += 1 }
  => {1=>3, 2=>2, 4=>1, 3=>1}
```

Pretty cool, eh?

We can simulate this using [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-next). The first value of `enum` (`[1, {}]`) is passed to the block and assigned to the block variables:

```
k,h = enum.next
  #=> [1, {}] 
k #=> 1 
h #=> {}
```

and we compute:

```
h[k] += 1
  #=> h[k] = h[k] + 1  (what '+=' means)
  #        = 0 + 1 = 1 (h[k] on the right equals the default value
  #                     of 1 since `h` has no key `k`)
```

so now:

```
h #=> {1=>1}
```

Next, `each` passes the second value of `enum` into the block and similar calculations are performed:

```
k,h = enum.next
  #=> [2, {1=>1}] 
k #=> 2 
h #=> {1=>1} 
h[k] += 1
  #=> 1 
h #=> {1=>1, 2=>1}
```

Things are a little different when the third element of `enum` is passed in, because `h` now has a key `1`:

```
k,h = enum.next
  #=> [1, {1=>1, 2=>1}] 
k #=> 1 
h #=> {1=>1, 2=>1} 
h[k] += 1
  #=> h[k] = h[k] + 1
  #=> h[1] = h[1] + 1  
  #=> h[1] = 1 + 1 => 2
h #=> {1=>1, 2=>1}
```

The remaining calculations are performed similarly.

Comment: thank you for explaining this in such depth, it really helped me get a better understanding of the code